# Pandas Styler - Custom Formatter for Names of MultiIndex

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, multi-index, styler

I've been trying to format a pandas dataframe using the styler. The behavior of `format_index()` seems a bit unpredictable when using a MultiIndex and I can't figure out a way to format the names of the MultiIndex.

The following is a MWE with an extremely stupid formatter:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data = {
    'Index1': ['A', 'B', 'C'],
    'Index2': ['X', 'Y', 'Z'],
    'Index3': ['1', '2', '3'],
    'Value1': np.random.randint(1, 100, 3),
    'Value2': np.random.randint(1, 100, 3),
    'Value3': np.random.randint(1, 100, 3)
}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df.set_index(['Index1', 'Index2', 'Index3'], inplace=True)

def custom_formatter(value):
    return 'S' + str(value)

styled_df = df.rename_axis(index=custom_formatter, columns=custom_formatter).style
styled_df = styled_df.format(custom_formatter).format_index(custom_formatter, axis=1).format_index(custom_formatter, axis = 0)
latex_table = styled_df.to_latex()
print(latex_table)
```

This results in

```
\begin{tabular}{lllrrr}
\toprule
 &  & SNone & SValue1 & SValue2 & SValue3 \\
SIndex1 & SIndex2 & SIndex3 &  &  &  \\
\midrule
SA & SX & S1 & S62 & S81 & S52 \\
SB & SY & S2 & S15 & S24 & S25 \\
SC & SZ & S3 & S22 & S36 & S48 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
```

This is nearly what I want (i.e. the formatter is used for all table elements), however the `SNone` should actually be blank - there is no value defined there. If I remove the `.rename_axis(...)` portion, it is blank.

Does anyone have any other ideas how to format the MultiIndex properly or how to get rid of this bug? My main goal here in having the indices is for common values to be grouped in multirows in latex, if there are ways to achieve that without indices, I'd also be open to suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because `df.columns.name` is [`None`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#none) and when you cast it to [`str`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-str), you get a literal `"None"`.

You can fix it this way :

```
def custom_formatter(value):
    return f"S{value}" if value else ""
```

Output :

```
>>> print(styled_df.to_latex())

\begin{table}
\.index_name.level0:nth-of-type(3)lightgreen
\begin{tabular}{lllrrr}
 &  &  & SValue1 & SValue2 & SValue3 \\
SIndex1 & SIndex2 & SIndex3 &  &  &  \\
SA & SX & S1 & S45 & S68 & S84 \\
SB & SY & S2 & S48 & S68 & S22 \\
SC & SZ & S3 & S65 & S10 & S37 \\
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

[image]

Comment: Ah got it, thanks! I didn't think of the columns.name. Although, I would have then expected it to be a muticolumn spanning the three indices instead of only the last one.

Comment: Also, I see you were trying to get the set_table_styles to work presumably (`\.index_name.level0:nth-of-type(3)lightgreen`). What was the command for that and would it work to set the formatter over the formatter key that way? I had trouble figuring out to the correct index_name key.

Comment: You're welcome. Regarding your first comment, no, only MultiIndex objects have a list of names. Your column/header is a (*flat*) Index, so it has a single name and will be located (*visually*) at the very right column of rows indices. And for the styling part, if you can tell what you exactly need, I can try doing that and update the answer.

Comment: I was trying to get something like 
```styled_df = df.style.set_table_styles([
    {'selector': 'index_name',
     'props': [('font-weight', 'bold'))],
     'formatter': custom_formatter}
])``` to work instead of setting the `.format`, `.format_index` and `rename` separately. But none of this seemed to work with to_latex(), even when setting convert_css to True. Mostly, I think I'm not getting the selector names correct

Comment: Yes that is an invalid css selector. Can you explain *exactly* what styles do you want to apply to `df` ?

Comment: I want to apply the custom formatter to all the cells shown in the latex table (so MultiIndex names and indices , as well as column names and the column values. I'd then also like to make the MultiIndex names and column names bold (so Index1-3 and Value1-3), and use the escape-'latex-math' mode. Sorry if the terminology is wrong, this is one of the first times working with MultiIndices for me, but I hope it's clear.

Comment: Is there a guide to the selector names? The default css_class)dict names mentioned https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.io.formats.style.Styler.set_table_styles.html don't seem to be specific enough, and I don't understand the goal of the examples like `tr:hover` or `th.col_heading` used at https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/style.html Also, the `map_index` command can't be used to specify a formatter, correct?

Comment: Your question becomes a *moving target* and I'm afraid I can't follow you anymore. If you're able to describe (*in detail*) the styles you need, I'll see if I can help ;)

Comment: Sorry, maybe simplest would be - how did you create `\.index_name.level0:nth-of-type(3)lightgreen`? I think with a good example, I can start to figure it out.

Comment: I did that to only highlight the empty `df.columns.name` (*after being formatted*). `styled_df.set_table_styles([{"selector": ".index_name.level0:nth-of-type(3)", "props": "background: lightgreen"}])`. Good luck ;)

Comment: pandas styler cannot format or style index name cells. The work around for columns is to recast the indexes as columns and then style those.